# JPlayer Controls Stop Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, controls, jplayer

I am using JPlayer to play Audios in a PhoneGap application ported to xCode to run on iPhone/iPad.

The JPlayer is inside a collapsible Div. It works fine as long as the Div is open. As soon as I Collapse the div (Manually or programmatically) and reopen it the controls (seek bar, start/stop buttons etc.) stop functioning. Like Stop button doesn't stop the Audio, Duration and Current time disappear and I only see Zeros etc.

Anyone has any idea please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution that ultimately worked was a work around. I removed the collapsible property from the Div and thru an onclick() function I controlled its height to expand and contract the div. This way JPlayer was fooled to believe that it is still visible.